# My DIV wont listen to me

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with my `div` staying withing my other `div`.

No matter what position I give it, the `div` will either jump to the top of the page or not show.

**CSS:**

```
.content {
  width:100%;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.contentinside {
  postition: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 960px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:#000099;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
<div class="contentinside">something here</div>
```

Comment: In addition to not closing the content div you also have a typo.   Should be position: relative and you have postition: relative.

Comment: You need to add `obey: me` to the styles.

Comment: Point your shotgun in it's general direction. A few warning shots at surrounding divs should get its attention.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want it to do, possibly show a fiddle?

Comment: @varubi he's having a hard time convincing the div to stay inside the other div. maybe a drafted letter of agreement might work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to close off your first `div` tag.

```
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="contentinside">something here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to put your first div inside the other div like below..you missing the end of second div

```
<div class="content">
<div class="contentinside">something here</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.content {
  position: relative;
  /* rest of your styles */
}

.contentinside {
  position: absolute;
  /* rest of your styles */
}
```

Now the positioning of .contentinside is relative to .content.
Of course, check closing tags properly, typos, etc.